# How to place this (from web GUI) stop loss order to close short position on huobi using rest API?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, huobi

I'm trying to place a stop loss to that should trigger to "close" a short position on Huobi via the rest API.

This is the position currently, about 3.4% in profit:

[image]

The current order book looks like so:

[image]

Via the web interface I can easily enter a stop loss trigger price of 0.066065 USDT like so:

[image]

After which this order is actually accepted:

[image]

However, via the rest API I don't manage.

I'm using the end-point:
`POST /linear-swap-api/v1/swap_cross_order`

Question:

What POST parameters to send?

When I'm sending this:

```
{'contract_code': 'TRX-USDT',
 'direction': 'buy',
 'lever_rate': 1,
 'offset': 'close',
 'order_price_type': 'limit',
 'sl_trigger_price': 0.066065,
 'volume': '14'}
```

I get an error:

`The price is not reasonable.`

and when I try this:

```
{'contract_code': 'TRX-USDT',
 'direction': 'buy',
 'lever_rate': 1,
 'offset': 'close',
 'order_price_type': 'market',
 'sl_trigger_price': 0.066065,
 'volume': '14'}
```

I get `Open a position with market price is not available.contracts`

In reaction to the last error message I even tried this:

```
{'contract_code': 'TRX-USDT',
 'direction': 'sell',
 'lever_rate': 1,
 'offset': 'open',
 'order_price_type': 'limit',
 'sl_trigger_price': 0.066065,
 'volume': '14'}
```

Getting also the:
`The price is not reasonable.`

So ... how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was using the wrong end-point.

This is the correct end-point:

`POST /linear-swap-api/v1/swap_cross_trigger_order`

With these parameters:

```
{'contract_code': 'TRX-USDT',
 'direction': 'buy',
 'lever_rate': 1,
 'offset': 'close',
 'order_price': 0.06607,
 'order_price_type': 'limit',
 'trigger_price': 0.066065,
 'trigger_type': 'ge',
 'volume': 28}
```

Leading to the stop loss as desired:

[image]